# Setting JButton text to align to the left?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, alignment, text-alignment

I previously had a JLabel, that I wanted to be click-able. The easiest way I found to do this was make it a JButton and using the following code. It now looks like a JLabel

```
button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 2, 2, 2));
button.setBorderPainted(false);
button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
button.setFocusPainted(false);
```

Which is exactly what I wanted except the text is now aligned in the middle. Now from what I was able to read on other questions and searching. This should work

```
button.setHorizontalTextPosition( SwingConstants.LEFT );
```

Yet, the text still aligns in the middle of the button. Any ideas what I can do to change this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to use

```
  setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT)
```

HorizontalTextPosition refers to the position of text in relation to the icon.

Answer (score 10):

Try

```
button.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
```